# How to aggregate and insert records in the dataframe based on condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, date

```
   COUNTRY   DATE         COMPANY   ITEM    SALES
0  TAIWAN   01-02-2019    CHINAM    TOY      2500
1  TAIWAN   05-02-2019    CHINAM    TOY      2500
2  TAIWAN   26-02-2019    CHINAM    TOY      2500
3  TAIWAN   01-02-2019    CHINAM    CERAMIC  500
4  TAIWAN   05-02-2019    CHINAM    CERAMIC  5500
5  TAIWAN   26-02-2019    CHINAM    CERAMIC  6500
6  TAIWAN   01-02-2019    CHINAM    KITCHEN  4500
7  TAIWAN   05-02-2019    CHINAM    KITCHEN  4500
8  TAIWAN   26-02-2019    CHINAM    KITCHEN  2300
```

I NEED TO AGGREGATE DATA BASED ON SOME CONDITION:
IF THE LAST DAY OF MONTH IN THE DATA FRAME IS SHORTER THAN THE ACTUAL LAST DAY OF MONTH i.e 28-02-2019, THEN I NEED TO AGG. DATA ON ITEM LEVEL AND INSERT THAT RECORD IN THE DATA FARME.

SUPPOSE IN MY DF LAST DATE 26-02-2019 BUT ACTUAL CALENDAR LAST DATE IS 28-02-2019.
IN THIS CONDITION I NEED TO AGGREGATE ON 'ITEM' LEVEL & INSERT RECORD IN THE DF ELSE DO NOTHING.

OUTPUT :

```
   COUNTRY   DATE         COMPANY   ITEM    SALES
0  TAIWAN   01-02-2019    CHINAM    TOY      2500
1  TAIWAN   05-02-2019    CHINAM    TOY      2500
2  TAIWAN   26-02-2019    CHINAM    TOY      2500
3  TAIWAN   01-02-2019    CHINAM    CERAMIC  500
4  TAIWAN   05-02-2019    CHINAM    CERAMIC  5500
5  TAIWAN   26-02-2019    CHINAM    CERAMIC  6500
6  TAIWAN   01-02-2019    CHINAM    KITCHEN  4500
7  TAIWAN   05-02-2019    CHINAM    KITCHEN  4500
8  TAIWAN   26-02-2019    CHINAM    KITCHEN  2300
9  TAIWAN   01-02-2019    CHINAM    TOY      7500
10 TAIWAN   05-02-2019    CHINAM    CERAMIC  12500
11 TAIWAN   05-02-2019    CHINAM    KITCHEN  11300
```

Comment: Why are you dates in the inserted records 1-2-2019 , 5-2-2019, and 5-2-2019?  What is the logic for those dates?

Comment: Sorry about that, we cannot simply group by dates, inplace of date I just need last date + 7 days  = 05-03-2019. there is no need to groupby dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df_sums = (df.groupby(['COUNTRY', 'COMPANY', 'ITEM'])[['DATE','SALES']]
             .agg(DATE=('DATE', lambda x: x.iloc[-1] + pd.Timedelta(days=7)),
                  SALES=('SALES', 'sum')).reset_index())

pd.concat([df, df_sums])
```

Output:

```
  COUNTRY       DATE COMPANY     ITEM  SALES
0  TAIWAN 2019-01-02  CHINAM      TOY   2500
1  TAIWAN 2019-05-02  CHINAM      TOY   2500
2  TAIWAN 2019-02-26  CHINAM      TOY   2500
3  TAIWAN 2019-01-02  CHINAM  CERAMIC    500
4  TAIWAN 2019-05-02  CHINAM  CERAMIC   5500
5  TAIWAN 2019-02-26  CHINAM  CERAMIC   6500
6  TAIWAN 2019-01-02  CHINAM  KITCHEN   4500
7  TAIWAN 2019-05-02  CHINAM  KITCHEN   4500
8  TAIWAN 2019-02-26  CHINAM  KITCHEN   2300
0  TAIWAN 2019-03-05  CHINAM  CERAMIC  12500
1  TAIWAN 2019-03-05  CHINAM  KITCHEN  11300
2  TAIWAN 2019-03-05  CHINAM      TOY   7500
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought (assuming this solution will be used on multiple years so you can't just group by month) is splitting the date into three columns: month, day, year. Then something like this group by:

```
df.groupby(["month", "year"]).agg({ITEM: lambda x: np.nan if is_last_day(x["day"].max(), x["month"], x["year"]) else aggregating_method(x["ITEM"]) } )
```

Where the is_last_day method could be done nicely with date time methods, and aggregating method is however you want to aggregate. Sorry if the code isn't exactly working, as I couldn't test it, but hopefully it gives an idea of the thought process. Let me know if you have any other questions, or if I completely misunderstood your question. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry about that, we cannot simply group by dates, inplace of date I just need last date + 7 days  = 05-03-2019. there is no need to groupby dates